# Temporary queue creation from python STOMP

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I want to create temporary queue for python(stomp).
    In the docs they have provided the reply-to header. but its not creating any temporary queue.
    Both producer and consumer files written in python.
 Does python STOMP really has a way to implement temporary queue.

I am sending a message with reply-to header.
In subscribers on_message listener i am checking whether reply-to header exist and if it does then it sends the response to reply-to header value.

Queue Producer

```py
import stomp
import json

class QueueProducer:

    def __init__(self):
            self.hosts = ['somevalue']
            self.ports = ['somevalue']
            self.ENCODE_FORMAT = "UTF-8"
            self.conn_param = zip(self.hosts,self.ports)
            self.conn = stomp.Connection11(self.conn_param, encoding=self.ENCODE_FORMAT)
            self.conn.start()
            self.conn.connect(wait=True)
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex

    def send_msg(self,message,queue_name,header={"JMSDeliveryMode":"Persistent",
                                                 "JMSPriority":4}):
        try:
            message = json.dumps(message)
            self.conn.send(destination='/queue/{}'.format(queue_name), body=message,
                            headers=header)
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = QueueProducer()
    from datetime import datetime
    obj.send_msg(str(datetime.now()),"MessageLife",header={"JMSDeliveryMode":"Persistent",
                                                 "JMSPriority":4,'reply-to':"destination", })
```

QUEUE CONSUMER:

```py
import sys
import stomp
import time
import json

ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL = "client-individual"

class CustomListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):

    def __init__(self,conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error::%s' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        try:
            message = json.loads(message)
            response = [1,2,3]
            self.conn.ack(headers.get("message-id"), int(headers.get("subscription")))
            if 'reply-to' in headers:
                self.conn.send(destination='/queue/{}'.format(headers.get("reply-to")),
                                body=json.dumps(response))

        except Exception as ex:
            print("exception nack")

class QueueConsumer:

    def __init__(self):
        try:

            self.hosts = ["some value",]
            self.ports = ["some value",]
            self.ENCODE_FORMAT = "utf-8"
            self.conn_param = zip(self.hosts,self.ports)
            self.conn = stomp.Connection11(self.conn_param, encoding=self.ENCODE_FORMAT)
            self.conn.start()
            self.conn.connect(wait=True,)
            self.conn.set_listener('', CustomListener(self.conn))
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex

    def consume_msg(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.conn.subscribe('/queue/{}'.format(self.queue_name),1, ack=ACK_CLIENT_INDIVIDUAL,
                                headers={"activemq.prefetchSize":1}
                                )
                time.sleep(500)
                self.conn.unsubscribe(1)
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex

    def execute(self):
        try:
            self.queue_name = "sample_queue"
            self.consume_msg()
            self.close_connection()
        except Exception as ex:
            raise ex

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = QueueConsumer()
    obj.execute()
```

I really want to know whether reply-to header create a temporary queue like java.(createTemporaryQueue method) or we have to manually create the queue(Either in sender or in consumer).
If anyone has code sample in python STOMP.py it will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about a message header named `reply-to` in STOMP. The [STOMP protocol specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html) doesn't say anything about a header named `reply-to`, and it also doesn't mention anything about creating temporary queues for any reason.

That said, ActiveMQ implements some extensions to STOMP so that if you send a message or create a consumer using a `destination` header which starts with `/temp-queue/` then a temporary queue will be created.

Comment: There are extensions in ActiveMQ 5 that do allow this 'reply-to' header and temp destination addressing to work: http://activemq.apache.org/stomp

Comment: My reading of that documentation indicates that it only maps corresponding JMS message headers to STOMP message headers (e.g. `JMSReplyTo` to `reply-to`), not that it actually creates temporary destinations on behalf STOMP clients.

Comment: It does indeed create them: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/LegacyFrameTranslator.java#L200

Comment: Right so the broker *can* create a temporary queue for a STOMP client if it uses `/temp-queue/` in the `destination` header. I'll update my answer.